# to show loading while navigating a web page using c# .net browser

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

hiii
I am developing a window application  in which I am showing a web page using  c# .net browser. since my web page is quite heavy and its taking time  to load . so i want  to show loading image while navigating a web page .so tell me how should i do .

Comment: You should tag this for windows forms or wpf (whichever you are using) as this is really more of a question around how to implement this using one of those technologies.

Comment: no I am  working with window form only here I am using .net browser to show web page in form .

Comment: You should consider marking some of the answers to your questions as accepted. Or give feedback so that the people who answered may know what to correct. Remember that your question is a resource for someone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using the WebBrowser wrapper, is that correct?
You can use the ProgressChanged and/or Navigating + DocumentCompleted events.

As an asside:
Depending on the nature of your application you could pre-download parts of the page to improve the user’s pereption of the app’s responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

It may sound overly simple, but it might be the easiest solution to just add an image control with an animated bitmap to the form at runtime when the page starts loading. Once it's done, just hide the image again. This would also give you the flexability to display any messages you want and add effects/transitions to make it aesthetically pleasing.

Answer (score 0):

Only since you asked so nicely.

You could just do this by monitoring both the navigating and the documentcompleted events of the webbrowser control. (Im sure you can fill in the blanks here).

Be sure when you use the documentcompleted event that you check the readystate :

```
theBrowser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
```

Otherwise the documentcompleted event will fire multiple times even before the entire page has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

First create an image(give a name for it) and place it wherever you want it but make the Visibility to Collapsed.

Then in your browser_**Navigating**, add this code, ImageName.Visibility = Visibility.**Visible**;

and then in your browser_**Navigated**, add this code, ImageName.Visibility = Visibility.**Collapsed**;